# Model empty on multi part page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

Sorry for the poor title.

I am trying to make a Recover Password page. I was going to do it all as a single page with multiple states depending on the model information (perhaps this is not a good way to do it).

Recovery has 4 steps

1. Validate User entered email
2. Validate user entered answer to first
   security question
3. Validate user entered answer for second security
   question
4. Show message saying that an Email has been sent with a link
   to reset password.

   ```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult RecoverPassword()
   {
       return View(new RecoverPassword());
   }
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult RecoverPassword(RecoverPassword model)
   {
       var user = new Identity("", "");
       ASResponse<string> asr;
       switch (model.View)
       {
           case "One":
               try
               {
                   asr = Services.ValidateSecurityQuestionOne(user.Token, model.Email, model.Answer);
                   model.View = "Two";
                   model.Question = "Your Other Favorite Color"; //asr.Payload;
                   model.Answer = string.Empty;
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("Question", "Incorrect Answer");
               }
               break;
           case "Two":
               try
               {
                   asr = Services.ValidateSecurityQuestionTwo(user.Token, model.Email, model.Answer);
                   model.View = "Email";
                   model.Question = string.Empty;
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("Question", "Incorrect Answer");
               }

               break;
           case "Email": break;
           default:
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email))
               {
                   try
                   {
                       asr = Services.ValidateEmail(user.Token, model.Email);
                       model.View = "One";
                       model.Question = asr.Payload;
                   }
                   catch (Exception)
                   {
                       ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Invalid Email");
                   }

               }
               break;
       }

       return View(model);
   }


   <div>
   <div>Retrieve your password</div>
   @{

   using (@Html.BeginForm())
   {

   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.View)

   switch (Model.View)
   {
       case "One":
       case "Two":
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email)
           <h3>@Model.Question</h3>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Answer)
           <br/>
           <input type="submit" value="Next" />
           break;
       case "Email":
           <h3>Your email is on its way!</h3>
           break;
       default:

           <h3>Please enter your Account Email Address</h3>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
           <br/>
           <input type="submit" value="Next" />
           break;
   }
   }    

   }

   </div>
   ```

With the above, I enter email, I get the first question, but when i submit that answer, model.View is null and so it goes back to email question.

Whats the appropriate way to create a setup like this? OR how can I get my model to always have the View and Email?

Comment: I don't know if an ajax post back is an option but I think that would work a lot better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.View) in your view and move it inside each switch condition, like so:

```
switch (Model.View)
{
    case "One":
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email)
        <h3>@Model.Question</h3>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Answer)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.View)
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        break;
    case "Two":
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email)
        <h3>@Model.Question</h3>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Answer)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.View)
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        break;
    case "Email":
        <h3>Your email is on its way!</h3>
        break;
    default:

        <h3>Please enter your Account Email Address</h3>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        break;
}
```